# Changing the subsection color modify page header

Tags: header-footer, titlesec, sectsty

Here is my problem: I'm trying to recreate my university template.

I created an `article` document where the first page has a different header and footer than the other pages. It's a little bit dirty but it works...

The header on the first page is longer than the ones on the others.

Then I wanted to change the color of my sections, subsections...
I used the `titlesec` package to modify the color and when I change the `section` color, there is no problem, but when I change the `subsection` color, my header on my second and following pages become too big (like the one on first page).

The document is on [GitHub](https://github.com/timbolle/ESC_latex_template/tree/master/article_template). It's the `article_template` and you can run the `my_document.tex`.

The minimum working exemple:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

% French or english language
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}

% To write special caracters
% to be used with Linux/Windows
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Set the fonts
% Palatino for rm and math | Helvetica for ss | Courier for tt
\usepackage{mathpazo} % math & rm
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet} % ss
\usepackage{courier} % tt
%\normalfont % the default
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% to write the text in sans serif
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}

% Set the spacing
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\colorlet{punct}{red!60!black}
\definecolor{background}{HTML}{EEEEEE}
\definecolor{delim}{RGB}{20,105,176}
\colorlet{numb}{magenta!60!black}
\definecolor{blue_title}{RGB}{46,116,181}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{blue_title}}
%\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries\color{blue_title}}
%\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\color{blue_title}}


% set the margin
% Taille des marges
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=4cm, left=2.5cm , right=2.5cm, includehead, showframe]{geometry}
%\usepackage{geometry}
%\geometry{bindingoffset=1cm} % to bind pages
\usepackage{afterpage}

% to be able to use landscape
\usepackage{lscape}

% To skip indent at the begining of paragraphs
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

% For quotes adapted in the
\usepackage{csquotes}

% for bullet points
\usepackage{enumitem}

% Footnote definition
\usepackage[hang, bottom]{footmisc}

%Pour le header
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \setlength\headheight{45pt}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width=1.56in, height=0.55in]{example-image}}
    \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}

\fancypagestyle{my_style}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width=5.5in, height=1in]{example-image}}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\includegraphics[width=6.7in, height=0.7in]{example-image}}
    }



\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}



\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}

\newgeometry{top=1.5cm, bottom=4cm, left=2.5cm , right=2.5cm, includehead}
\setlength\headheight{81pt}
\setlength\footskip{56pt}


\thispagestyle{my_style}
%\vspace*{0.5cm}
\Huge % size
\textbf{Magnificient Title}
%\rule{5cm}{0.2pt}

\large
\textcolor{gray}{
Subtitle --- \today
}

\setcounter{page}{1}
\afterpage{\aftergroup\restoregeometry}


\section*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract} % adds an entry to the table of contents
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{The First Section}
\subsection{With a sub secion}
\subsubsection*{and again}

\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

With this, it works:

The first page:
[image: The first page works]

And the second page and following:
[image: The second page is fine (subsection is in black)]

Note that in the **head/settings_esc_template.tex**, the line `\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries\color{blue_title}}` is commented.

Now, if I put the subsection (or the subsubsection) in blue by uncommenting the line `\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries\color{blue_title}}`, my heading on the second page change...

[image: Second page has a wrong header (subsection in blue)]

The behavior is the same with the `sectsty` package.

Does anyone has an explanation for this behavior?

Thank you for your help (and sorry for my english mistakes)!

Comment: Put your code in *one* document and post it here.  And replace the graphics by example-image.  (But I would avoid afterpage and aftergroup)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for your suggestions. I edited the question following them. What would you suggest to use instead of \afterpage and \aftergroup to modify the style of the first page, independently of the content (no \clearpage or \newpage)?

Comment: The document doesn't compile on my system as files are missing.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry, forgot one \include. It's good now. I compile it alone and it shoud work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to do complicated resetting of the geometry. Simply use \vspace and \enlargethispage and smash the height of the images so that they can stick into the pages:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[english,french]{babel}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\color{blue}}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries\color{blue}}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\color{blue}}

%page layout of second and following pages, adapt the values if needed
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=4cm, left=2.5cm , right=2.5cm, 
           includehead, headheight=45pt, showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width=1.56in, height=0.55in]{example-image}}
    \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}

\fancypagestyle{my_style}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
    %raise the boxes and smash their height on page 1, adapt the values
    \fancyhead[L]{%
     \raisebox{-2cm}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[width=5.5in, height=1in]{example-image}}}
    \fancyfoot[C]{%
     \raisebox{-0.5cm}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[width=6.7in, height=0.7in]{example-image}}}
    }

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}

\thispagestyle{my_style}
\vspace*{0.5cm}  %adapt to move the text down
\enlargethispage{-1cm} %adapt to shorten the first page if needed
\Huge % size
\textbf{Magnificient Title}
%\rule{5cm}{0.2pt}

\large
\textcolor{gray}{Subtitle --- \today}

\section*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract} % adds an entry to the table of contents
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{The First Section}
\subsection{With a sub secion}
\subsubsection*{and again}

\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: It worked thank you! initially, I created another geometry because the bigger image on the first page was enlarging the header for all pages but it seems to not be the case anymore. Thanks again!